# Checking for input live/with key strokes in HTML input field with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, field, live

I need to find a way to hide the span with the ID 'forgot' as soon as the field has any input. The only time the 'forgot' span should be visible is when the field is empty.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username or E-mail" autofocus><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" id='pass' placeholder="Password"><br>
    <span id="forgot">( <a class="forgot" href="<?php echo $dom; ?>forgot/">forgot?</a> )</span>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

I currently have this script....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keypress(function() {
        var value=$.trim($("#pass").val());
        if (value.length==0) {
            $('#forgot').css("display","initial");
        } else {
            $('#forgot').css("display","none");
        }
    }
});
```

Is there any better way to check for live input from a user and get it to run a function?

Comment: Define "better way".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('keypress', '#pass', function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value.length) {
            // $('#forgot').css("display", "block");
            // Or
            $('#forgot').show();
        } else {
            // $('#forgot').css("display", "none");
            // Or
            $('#forgot').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

1. You shouldn't be adding event on `document`, add on `pass` instead
2. Use `show`/`hide` functions
3. Use `display`: `block` instead of `initial`
4. No need to compare to `==0`

Comment: So would it be $('#pass').on('keypress'... ?? What effect does using initial have?

Comment: @EnayetHussain Both are same, but it will not work if you are adding `pass` dynamically. Added just in case.

Comment: I cant seem to get the code to work. The website is live on http://enayet.co.uk/login/ I'd appreciate it if you could have a little look

Comment: @EnayetHussain DId you add the code on the live website

Comment: Yeah its viewable on that page. I put it inside script tags.

Comment: @EnayetHussain Silly mistake! missed `);` of `keypress`. Check updated answer.

Comment: @EnayetHussain No need to use `hide` and `css` both functions. Shown only for understanding. Only use one of the above.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help and yeah I decided to remove the CSS one. I got some issue with the Login button moving once forgot vanishes but thats just CSS I'll sort that out!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('input', '.Required', function(){
    var required = false;
    var elems = $('.Required');
    for(var i in elems){
    if($(elems[i]).val() == ''){
       required = true;
    }
}
if(required){
  $('#forgot').show();
}else{
  $('#forgot').hide();
}

 });
```

On my mobile and untested.Add the class Required to the input fields. It should display if any field with that class name.